# Linear algebra - Basic question on matrices and polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix over a field $K$.

How do I formally define $f(A)$ for a polynomial $f\in K[x]$?

Answer (score 1):

You have to think to a polynomial's constant term as $a_0x^0$; then you substitute $x$ with $A$; for instance, if $f(x)=x^2-3x+2=x^2-3x^1+2x^0$, you have
$$
f(A)=A^2-3A^2+2A^0=A^2-3A+2I
$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Replace $x$ by $A$. Ex: $x^2 + 1 \rightarrow A^2 + 1$.